# Is it possible to get the successor and predecessor of a hash key in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I wonder if something like this is possible without iterating over the whole hash:

```
collection = { red: 1000, green: 120, "yellow" => 1, blue: 999 }
```

Something like this:

```
collection.next_key(:red)    #Should return :green
collection.prev_key(:blue)   #Should return "yellow"
```

**EDIT::** I was hoping to somehow access the `fore` and `back` member of the internal Ruby Hash data structure:

```
struct st_table_entry {
  unsigned int hash;
  st_data_t key;
  st_data_t record;
  st_table_entry *next;
  st_table_entry *fore, *back; // new in Ruby 1.9
};
```

([Source](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/))

Comment: Aren't hashes unordered?

Comment: Up until Ruby 1.9. After then, Hashes are ordered.

Comment: They used to be, but since 1.9 they are ordered.

Comment: For completeness: they're ordered by insertion order. That may or may not be what you actually *want* when you say next/prev, particularly if the hash is modified.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it will work

```
class Hash
  def next_key(key)
    self.keys[self.keys.find_index(key) + 1]
  end
  def prev_key(key)
    self.keys[self.keys.find_index(key) - 1]
  end
end
```

But remember that is `Hash` so order of items can be different from that one you write.

Comment: It will, but with iterating over the hash

Comment: Yes but not the whole hash, only half of it. (On average)